# what is and how to upgrade nvidia Runtime API Version?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

When I run a process that uses paddle, an error occured:

> W1206 13:55:49.811826 22388 device_context.cc:447] Please NOTE:
> device: 0, GPU Compute Capability: 6.1, Driver API Version: 11.5,
> Runtime API Version: 10.2 W1206 13:55:49.812117 22388
> dynamic_loader.cc:287] The third-party dynamic library (libcudnn.so)
> that Paddle depends on is not configured correctly. (error code is
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory)   Suggestions:
>
> 1. Check if the third-party dynamic library (e.g. CUDA, CUDNN) is installed correctly and its version is matched with paddlepaddle you
>    installed.
> 2. Configure third-party dynamic library environment variables as follows:
>
> - Linux: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`
> - Windows: set PATH by `set PATH=XXX;

doesn't have a clue what is Runtime API Version and how to upgrade it to 11.5 (as same as   Driver API Version).Any help would be appreciated~

os:
ubuntu 18.04

nvidia-smi:
NVIDIA-SMI 495.44       Driver Version: 495.44       CUDA Version: 11.5